# SQL JOIN - Map value from one table to its equivalent in another during the JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following scenario:

```
Table 1 - Holds product meta data about products.
Table 2 - Holds sales data about the products.
```

Each table has a unique ID for the products, however for historical reasons the ID's in the tables are different. For example:

```
In Table 1, "Red Hat" -> 1
In Table 2, "Red Hat" -> 3.
```

I want to join Table 2 to Table 1, and map the rows based on product ID.

Is there a way to 'map' these values, so that all rows with Id 3 in Table 2 will be mapped to all rows in Table 1 with Id 1?

Comment: Please show sample data from both tables in _tabular_ format.  I don't think we can answer this based on just what you wrote above.

Comment: @Adam Ben-David you need to get match value in both tables if you want to map them in the other hand theres no way to do it. Did you try to map them by name? It's not the best practice but it could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` statement in the join `ON` clause for mapping.

**Demo.**

Prepare tables:

```
hive> create table testt1 as select 1 as key;
hive> create table testt2 as select 3 as key;
```

Join using case:

```
 select t1.key, t2.key 
   from testt1 t1 
        left join testt2 t2 
        on t2.key=case when t1.key=1 then 3 --add more cases 
                      --when t1.key=<some value> then <mapped value>
                        else t1.key          --default mapping t1.key=t2.key 
                  end
  ;
```

Result:

```
OK
1       3
Time taken: 41.191 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```